# Запустить анимацию элемента при скролле до него jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется изображение которое должно плавно появиться, при скролле до него.
Этот скрипт не срабатывает при большой высоте экрана:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.estm-phone-app img').each(function () {
        var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (imagePos < topOfWindow + 500) {
            $(this).addClass("animated slideInUp")
        }
    });
});
```

Судя по всему значение `500` не подходит. Существует ли какое-то универсальное решение чтобы скрипт срабатывал при любой не стандартной высоте экрана?

[Полный код](https://jsfiddle.net/sLpjLnwk/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

За место 500 подставь попробуй

```
$(window).innerHeight()
```

Comment: спасибо, это решение работает